# Please can I get some guidance on techniques using the Unique Function

Tags: excel

To clarify, I will attack the code myself, however, it's the order and techniques to do this I need some guidance with.

I have a table with 4 columns. The table has 40000 rows. The columns are Date, Name, location, company.
I want to see how many times someone in the name column, appears in the database. I then want to apply a date filter to that. This I have managed to do if somewhat clunky.

My problem is that the unique function only returns the name, when i apply it to that column. and i need it to return the location and company so that i can sort on that too. How would you go about doing that?

I have used unique on the name column. It returns a spilled over list of about 4000 names. I then
use this code =COUNTIFS(MyName,$A2,MyDate,">="&DATE(List!$D$2,List!M$4,List!M$5),MyDate,"<="&DATE(List!$D$2,List!M$4,List!M$3)) to return the number of entries per month. A2 is the unique return column.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Allan

Comment: Sounds like a pivot table might be simpler.

Comment: Small example dataset together with expected results would be useful.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, here is an example
Date Name Location Company

01/02/2021 A aa xx
01/02/2021 B bb xx
01/02/2021 C bb yy
01/02/2021 D dd yy
01/02/2021 A aa xx
02/02/2021 B bb yy
02/02/2021 C bb yy
02/02/2021 A aa xx
03/02/2021 B bb yy


expected result

 total 01/02/2021 02/02/2021 03/02/2021 location Company
a 3 2 1 0 aa xx
b 3 1 1 1 bb xx
c 2 1 1 0 bb yy
d 1 1 0 0 dd yy

I currently get everything apart from the last two columns. I am not sure how to get that. Happy to take advice.